# Can I use a graphic as the name of a variable?

Tags: graphics, variable-definitions

In *Mathematica*, is it possible to define a graphic variable/function? Something like 
$$\text{"A drawing of a pentagon''}[x\_]:=ax^5+bx^4?$$

Comment: What exactly are you expecting the output to be here? What do you mean that the graphic should be a function of `x`? And what does "drawing of a pentagon"  have to do with the function that you defined there? We need more details, with an explanation of your desired output, please.

Comment: @march, just an ordinary function f[x_]:=ax^5+bx^4, with f replaced by the picture of a pentagon.

Comment: Okay, that's not what I expected. Why would you want to do something like this?

Comment: @march, because I have a graph theory problem which needs me to assign different functions to different graphs, and I can't find a systematic and neat way of naming all the graphs. What I asked is nothing vital to my purpose, it's just that it would be nice book keeping.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may use the [Notation, Symbolize, and InfixNotation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/Notation/tutorial/NotationSymbolizeAndInfixNotation.html) tutorial to define your own notation.  This method has the added bonus of not unprotecting built-in symbols.

Below is a screenshot of the notebook followed by the code.  The screenshot is added because the `InputForm` of the templates from the `` Notation` `` package are not very easy to read.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Graphics[Polygon@CirclePoints@5, ImageSize -> 30]

Needs["Notation`"]
```

Paste the following to a new cell and convert the cell to StandardForm from the *Cell | Convert To* menu. This is the template from the Notation package palette that is not easy to read in input form.

```
Notation[ParsedBoxWrapper[
    RowBox[{GraphicsBox[PolygonBox[NCache[
         {{Sqrt[5/8 - Sqrt[5]/8], (-1 - Sqrt[5])/4}, 
          {Sqrt[5/8 + Sqrt[5]/8], (-1 + Sqrt[5])/4}, {0, 1}, 
          {-Sqrt[5/8 + Sqrt[5]/8], (-1 + Sqrt[5])/4}, 
          {-Sqrt[5/8 - Sqrt[5]/8], (-1 - Sqrt[5])/4}}, 
         {{0.5877852522924731, -0.8090169943749475}, 
          {0.9510565162951535, 0.30901699437494745}, {0, 1}, 
          {-0.9510565162951535, 0.30901699437494745}, 
          {-0.5877852522924731, -0.8090169943749475}}]], 
       ImageSize -> 30], "[", "x_", "]"}]] \[DoubleLongLeftRightArrow] 
   ParsedBoxWrapper[RowBox[{"poly", "[", "x_", "]"}]]]
```

In fact the remainder of the code will be just as unwieldy to read as it requires graphics in InputForm so I am going to skip adding it.

Basically you just paste the polygon into an input cell and use it as a symbol of a function with one parameter.

```
<pasted graphic>[value]
```

By assigning a definition to `poly` the *graphic symbol* will resolve to that function and evaluate.

```
poly[x_] := a x^5 + b x^4
```

Further *graphic symbols* can be created in the same manner by creating a new notation with the templates from the notation palette. Of course, each graphic will need its own function to map to.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. What's the use of Needs["Notation`"]?

Comment: @JiaYiyang It loads the ``Notation` `` package tat comes with Mathematica.

Answer (score 9):

What I think you want is indeed possible since *Mathematica* 6.  We need to unprotect [`Graphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics.html) to allow the rule to be attached, but then this works:

[image]

I copied and pasted the output of the first line into the definition on the third line, and the application on the fourth line.